# How to fill properties of objects using LINQ and return collection

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have file with lines like this: *05122018;surname1;ItemName1;Price1*

And OrderModel

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        public string ManagerSurname { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string CustomerSurname { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }

    }
```

How to make LINQ request to return collection of OrderModels ?

```
public IEnumerable<OrderModel> Parse(string[] input)
        {
            return
                (input ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)))
                .Select(orderModel => new OrderModel()
                {
                   //filling objects
                }).Where(orderModel => //Any);
```

Comment: whats the string[] input? with what do yo uwant to fill the fields? or more correctly how do they map to our array of input. Based on index  positoined on input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the `input[]` array consists of one line

> 05122018;surname1;ItemName1;Price1

for each entry and each line has the same order of items. You could do a split in the select, to get the appropriate values:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderModel> Parse(string[] input)
{
    return
        (input ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)))
        .Select(orderModel =>
        {
            var items = orderModel.Split(";");
            if (items.Length != 4)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            return new OrderModel()
            {
                //filling objects
                ManagerSurname = items[1],
                ItemName = items[2],
                ...
            };
        }).Where(orderModel =>  //Any);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you look like you want to `deserialize` the string that's coming in from semicolon delimited to an object. That's a pretty ugly and potentially fragile way to `serialize` / `deserialize` your data, and if you can change it (to `JSON`, or `XML` or something else) it might be a good idea.

But you could create a constructor for your `OrderModel` class that takes the serialized string as a parameter and deserializes in there:

```
public OrderModel(string inOrderModel){
    var splitString = inOrderModel.Split(';');
    ManagerSurname = splitString[1];
    // etc
}
```

And then you can use `LINQ` to create the list from the incoming array:

```
return input.Select(i => new OrderModel(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

returning simply `return _context.OrderModel` will return your entire OrderModel from the context:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderModel> Parse(string[] input)
{

(input ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)))

            return _context.OrderModel;
}
```

or assuming you would like to filter your dataset by data in the input string array, you can filter with `input.contains(model.field)`.  Example filters Item Name based on the input string array:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderModel> Parse(string[] input)
    {

    (input ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input)))

                return _context.OrderModel.Where(m => input.contains(m.ItemName));
    }
```

Comment: @croxy I guess I need more information in regards to what your actual issue is